# Pass integers and dictionary to function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def function2():


def function():
    function2(1, 5, {"name": "knuxyl"})
    enter code here
```

EDIT : I'm sorry for some reason I closed out of this and it still posted it... I figured it out mid way through writing it...

My Solution :

```
def function2(**kwargs):
    dosomestuff[f]


def function1():
    function2(f=1, i=5, n={"name": "knuxyl"})

function1()
```

For some reason, when I did function2 like

`function2(f, i, n)`

and called it like

`function2(1, 5, {"name": "knuxyl"})`

it treated the dictionary I passed through as a tuple. I printed type and value and it showed

`({"name": "knuxyl"}),`

I have no idea why it was doing this, so I just used kwargs with specific variables. The reason why I need kwargs is because variable i and n are not always passed

Comment: The %s specifier converts the object using str(), and %r converts it using repr()..

Comment: I don't see you have a complete code to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function2(a,b,c):
    print("A=%r,B=%r,C=%r"%(a,b,c))



def function():
    function2(1, 5, {"name": "knuxyl"})
```

... this is pretty basic, I think you need to do some more tutorials

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to post this, I stopped half way through. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

```
def function2(a,b,c):
    print(f"A={a},B={b},C={c}")


def function():
    function2(1, 5, {"name": "knuxyl"})
```

You can read more on f-strings in Python as well;